# identify elements of a bash array - determine if aws keys are 90 days old

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I have a line in my bash script that pulls the AWS access keys and the dates they were created for a user.

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user-name $user_name --profile=prod  | jq -r '.AccessKeyMetadata[] | (.AccessKeyId, .CreateDate)')
```

It outputs the information like this:

```
AKIAI6Q5EQ53GONANGBA
2018-07-05T21:28:39Z
AKIAICDOHVTMEAB6RM5Q
2018-02-08T03:55:51Z
```

I tried creating an array and looping for the array:

```
echo "User $user_name keys:"

   user_keys=( $(aws iam list-access-keys --user-name $user_name --profile=kpmg-prod  | jq -r '.AccessKeyMetadata[] | (.AccessKeyId, .CreateDate)' '\n') )
   for i in "$user_keys"
   do 
     echo "$user_keys"
   done
```

But all that gets me is this output:

```
User my_aws_user keys:
AKIAI6Q5EQ53GONANGBA
```

I want to assign the output of that command to an array. And print out the key and time stamp on one line. And use the time stamp to determine if the user's key is older than 90 days.

If it is older than 90 days it will perform some additional functions, that I already have worked out. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use the query parameter to get that info in one line. Here's the command: `aws iam list-access-keys --user-name $user_name --profile prod --output text --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[*].[AccessKeyId,CreateDate]'`. This should print the access key and created date in the same line. Use the awk command to get the necessary details.

Comment: Thanks it does. But if if I put that aws query into the array, it only prints out the first key and not the rest of the information: `User bob keys:
AKIAI6Q5EQ53GONANGBA`

Comment: Your script should read the response line-by-line. Try this command: `response=$(aws iam list-access-keys --user-name $user_name --profile prod --output text --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[*].[AccessKeyId,CreateDate]') ; while IFS= read -r line ; do key=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}'); date=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}'); echo "$key - $date" ; done <<< "$res"`. $key variable will have the access key id and $date will have the created date.

Comment: Thanks. When I try that code, it doesn't output anything: `User bob keys:
 - 
` is literally all it does. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If `user_keys` is an array, `$user_keys` and `${user_keys[0]}` are equivalent. You want

```
for i in "${user_keys[@]}"
do 
  echo "$i"
done
```

instead. (Expand the array to its entire contents, one element per word, and use the index in the loop of the body.)